# compare a two date columns of a data frame with another two data frames of second data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2
df1 contains month and two date columns

`df1`

```
Month      Month_Start    Month_End
Month1      2022-03-27    2022-04-30
Month2      2022-05-01    2022-05-28
Month3      2022-05-01    2022-06-25
```

another data frame `df2`

```
start_Month     end_Month      price
2022-03-27      2260-12-31      1
2022-03-27      2260-12-31      2
2022-03-27      2260-12-31      3
```

if `Month_Start` and `Month_end` of `df1` is in between `start_Month` and `end_Month` of df2, assign `price` column value to `Month` column of `df1`

like following result

```
Month   price
Month1      1
Month2      1
Month3      1
```

I tried using for loops

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if df2['start_Month'][i] <= df1['Month_Start'][j]<= df1['Month_End'][j] <= df2['end_Month'][i]:
            new.loc[len(new.index)] = [df1['month'][j], df2['price'][i]]
```

but taking lot of time for execution for 1000+ rows.

ANY IDEAS?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a common column where you can combine these two dataframes? such as **id**. If there is, it would be much more accurate to apply the conditions after combining these two tables. You can try the code below based on current data and conditions (Dataframes that are not the same size may have a problem.).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame(data={'Month':['Month1','Month2','Month3'],
                       'Month_Start':['2022-03-27','2022-05-01','2022-05-01'],
                       'Month_End':['2022-04-30','2022-05-28','2022-06-25']})

df2=pd.DataFrame(data={'start_Month':['2022-03-27','2022-03-27','2022-03-27'],
                       'end_Month':['2260-12-31','2260-12-31','2260-12-31'],
                 'price':[1,2,3]})

con=[(df1['Month_Start']>= df2['start_Month']) & (df1['Month_End']<= df2['end_Month'])]
cho=[df2['price']]
df1['price']=np.select(con,cho,default=np.nan)#
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Month': ['Month1', 'Month2', 'Month3'], 
                     'Month_Start': ['2022-03-27', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01'], 
                     'Month_End': ['2022-04-30', '2022-05-28', '2022-06-25'] })
df1['Month_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Month_Start'])
df1['Month_End'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Month_End'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'start_Month': ['2022-03-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01'], 
                     'end_Month': ['2022-04-30', '2022-05-30', '2022-06-30'],
                     'price': [1, 2, 3] })
df2['start_Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_Month'])
df2['end_Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end_Month'])

print(df1)
    Month Month_Start  Month_End
0  Month1  2022-03-27 2022-04-30
1  Month2  2022-05-01 2022-05-28
2  Month3  2022-05-01 2022-06-25

print(df2)    #note validity periods do not overlap, so only 1 price is valid!
  start_Month  end_Month  price
0  2022-03-01 2022-04-30      1
1  2022-05-01 2022-05-30      2
2  2022-06-01 2022-06-30      3
```

I would define an external function to check the validity period, then return the corresponding price. Note that if more than 1 corresponding validity periods are found, the first one will be returned. If no corresponding period is found, a null value is returned.

```
def check_validity(row):
    try:
        return int(df2['price'][(df2['start_Month']<=row['Month_Start']) & (row['Month_End']<=df2['end_Month'])].values[0])
    except:
        return
    
df1['price'] = df1.apply(lambda x: check_validity(x), axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Month Month_Start  Month_End  price
0  Month1  2022-03-27 2022-04-30    1.0
1  Month2  2022-05-01 2022-05-28    2.0
2  Month3  2022-05-01 2022-06-25    NaN
```